# Unable to see the value in output

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

I have been trying to figure out why this is not visible in the output, most likely its something to do with asynchronous nature of react, which is good. But what do need to do to show the contents up?

The Description column is blank!

https://codesandbox.io/embed/vibrant-field-700k2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

There is a usertable with master data:

```
{usrData.map((prop, key) => {
            return (
              <tr key={key}>
                <td className="text-center">{prop.id}</td>
{/* Returns Data */}
                <td className="text-left">
                  {
                    selectTimeOptions.filter(
                      dealer => dealer.value === prop.time_slot
                    )[0].label
                  }
                </td>
                {/* To double check data is present */}
                <td>{prop.customergarage}</td>
                <td>
                  {/* Does not return or show data */}
                  {/* But data visible in console */}
                  {[...prop.customergarage].forEach(d => {
                    if (parseInt(d, 10) > 0) {
                      const retrs = sTypes.filter(st => st.value === d)[0];
                      console.log(retrs);
                      return retrs;
                    }
                  })}
                </td>
                <td className="text-right" />
              </tr>
            );
          })}
```

Any explanations and/or fixes? Specially how to use React.useEffect() here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what you want to do with useEffect here, but I will try to explain why it is not rendering.

First of all, forEach does not work that way, so you cannot return from it.

Second, you can resolve all your issues with a function that builds the internal part.

```
buildCustomerData = (customergarage) => {
const good = [];
customergarage.forEach(d => {
                    if (parseInt(d, 10) > 0) {
                      const retrs = sTypes.filter(st => st.value === d)[0];
                      console.log(retrs);
                      good.push(retrs)
                    }
                  })
  return good;
}

{usrData.map((prop, key) => {
            return (
              <tr key={key}>
                <td className="text-center">{prop.id}</td>
{/* Returns Data */}
                <td className="text-left">
                  {
                    selectTimeOptions.filter(
                      dealer => dealer.value === prop.time_slot
                    )[0].label
                  }
                </td>
                {/* To double check data is present */}
                <td>{prop.customergarage}</td>
                <td>
                  {/* Does not return or show data */}
                  {/* But data visible in console */}
                  {buildCustomerData(prop.customergarage)}
                </td>
                <td className="text-right" />
              </tr>
            );
          })}
```

Just a map wont do the work in the internal loop, because you will have cases where your conditions will not be met.